# Laravel model ON method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, multi-tenant

Is on method respected on relations/ or even on nested relations?

For example:

```
User::on('conn1')->with('sports')->get();
```

or

```
$u = User::on('conn1')->where('id', 1)->first();
$u->sports;
```

Comment: `on`  is use for join 2 table https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses

Comment: For that too. I don't think this is in documentation, but when model is staticly called with using method on() - on() will define connection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the method "on" can be used to retrieve data from a table of a different connection.
eg. `User::on('conn1')->with('sports')->get();`

This is only valid if the table Sports belongs to that same connection. If sports belongs to another connection then make sure to define it in the Sports model like below

```
protected $connection = 'conn2';
```

Comment: I can't do that as this is multi-tenant app and I need data from all tenants merged. I hoped that framework will use connection from on method on all called relations using with().

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use the method on() then you can try this.

```
$user = new User;
$user->setConnection('conn1');
$u = $user->where('id', 1)->first();
```

then you can set connection in your User Model.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'conn1';

}
```

but this is also perfectly fine.

```
$user = User::on( 'conn1' )->where( 'id', 1 )->first();
```